# Running a game server - need more memory

Tags: java

Its actually a Minecraft server. I have 16GB of RAM on my desktop here running a 4 core processor each core at 3.0ghz speed and 4GB Video Memory. its a pretty beefy computer (especially back in the day) yet  it is still able to hold its own as a gaming computer even today running some pretty awesome games from Xboxone and whatever.

Well, I'm trying to run a game server on this desktop (I know it can handle it). Problem is, the server runs, but I can't see any of the mobs (NPC's creators of the world) on the map yet I can hear them. I know they are there. I can hear them. I go around my map, hearing them, but not seeing them.

I looked in other places on the web regarding this issue and found the issue is a memory issue (not enough memory). So I need to increase the memory of Java 8--problem is, it says in my server console "Ignoring max memory--support removed in 8.0" meaning though I set the memory in the bat file to run the server, it is ignoring how much I am telling it to use to run my server... and this is annoying.

Okay there is more details.

I entered a command in the server /memory

The server reports that the max memory allocated to the server is only a mere 1GB!!!! and I'm like WHAT!? Cuz I know I know I KNOW I have WAY more than that to offer my server! I need to increase that! So this is the issue.

To sum it up: Java 8 says it does not support max memory or min memory anymore if I were to set it up in a bat file to use 10,000MB (10GB) for my server when I run it--it ignores that... yet I need to force it to USE THAT AMMOUNT. how do I do this?

In control panel I already set it in the java, java tab, (field that is already there by default).

So I'm not sure what else to do.

Seems to me it was dumb of Java to remove support for memory heap customization in 8, makes me miss Java 7 if you ask me.

So any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: What flags did you actually change? Java *does* support min and max memory params in 8

Comment: what do you mean "flags"? I didn't change any flags... it is a .bat file. Spigot tells us a script to copy/paste into a txt file and to save it as a .bat file. there, in that file, we can set memory. In the .bat file this is what the script looks like:     @echo off

:restart                                                                                                           
java -XX:MaxPermSize=12000M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1342.jar

exit

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my console reporting that Java 8 is ignoring the command to use 10GB (at the time I made this screenshot I was telling it to use 12GB--then I changed it down to 10GB) Screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/bi98us705/

Comment: You're getting confused between `-Xmx` which is max heap and `-XX:MaxPermSize` which is the PermGen area.  The latter has been removed whereas the former hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java arguments include `-Xmx` and `-Xms`.

Read this question/answer for further details: [What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

Comment: Fixed! See in the past versions of Java, we didn't have to include the Xms, only the max is what we had to included and Java would automatically configure itself. (that is an old script above from years back that USE to work but only with Java 6 and 7) I hated Java 8 because of (screenshot above) what it was telling me in the console that support was removed. Looks like, it is REQUIRED that one must put both Xms and Xmx into the script. Now my script looks like this and it works: @echo off

:restart
java -Xmx12g -Xms4g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1342.jar

exit

Comment: THANK YOU! (didn't have enough characters left for this but had to be sure to say so!)

Comment: Make sure to mark the question as answered if my answer did in fact solve your problem.